# Migration from Liferay 6.2 CE GA5 to Liferay 7

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I use  Liferay 6.2 CE GA5 with some my portlets and information. And now I want to try to migrate it to version 7. I know that it is only beta version, but I just want to try. Is there any manual or documentation how to do that?
I've just tried to make DB dump from liferay6 and use it in liferay7 but it doesn't work. I need more information.

Comment: We need the log to see why doesn't work

Comment: https://dev.liferay.com/discover/deployment/-/knowledge_base/7-0/upgrading-to-liferay-7

Answer (score 1):

For migration from Liferay 6 to 7 you can visit [this](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/from-liferay-6-to-liferay-7) link 
and [this](https://dev.liferay.com/discover/deployment/-/knowledge_base/7-0/backing-up-a-liferay-installation) one can help you for backup and installation.

I myself recommend you migrate from 6 to 7 based on this [one](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/whats-changed-and-what-hasnt#modular-architecture).

Below, I denote some benefits of Liferay 7:

- Tomcat 8
- JDK 8
- Mysql 5.7
- Eclipse Update / Liferay IDE 3
- Bootstrap 3.0 Look and Feel
- Modularity - OSGI
- Lexicon Design Language
- set of patterns (visual and interaction)
- designed to be fluid and extensible
- Optimized product navigation
- New Forms user experience
- Geolocate any content
- New image, file and media selector
- Fast response - avoiding full page refreshes
- Single Page Applications – senna.js
- Very Good News - IE support 10,11/Edg
- Monolithic to Microservices
- Now 500+ new modules (bundles in the OSGi world),
- We can change any way we like, simply by overriding them with our own modules.
- Lucene Gone, Elastic Search(Separate Server)
- Optionally Solr, support only in EE
- Goodbye Ant, Hello Gradle (maven is still there)
- Build tool based on Node.js for Theme development
- New mobile SDK with Liferay screens 2
- Clustering not supported in CE